# Can DALEX be used for mlr3 surv models?

Tags: mlr3, dalex

I am not sure if I can use DALEX for my mlr3 survival models because y argument does not accept Surv(time, status). I also don't think results are correct when I use "status" for y since this ignores the censoring information.

https://modeloriented.github.io/DALEXtra/reference/explain_mlr3.html

If I can't use DALEX, are there alternative XAI tools for survival models?

Comment: Sorry this isn't supported yet

Comment: Thanks @RaphaelS, Are you aware of any alternative packages that can deal with survival model?

Comment: Sorry don't know any

Answer (score 1):

The DALEX package cannot deal with survival models directly.

However, recently the [survex](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survex) package has been created for explanations of survival models with the same intuitive API.

If you work specifically with mlr3 survival models, explainers for them can be created automatically, so if this issue is still of interest to you give it a look!

Comment: I am using mlr3 but I am not aware the package has built-in explainer. Can you please provide an example